# Turn off Ambiguous method call inspection Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I was under the impression that the @Override annotation was optional in Java...  Intellij is complaining about the following code:

Note that `ComboBox` extends `TextField`, and that both of these are in the GWT library and not my code.  Is there any way anyone knows of to stop the red.  I didn't have this problem in intellij 14, but now that I'm on the latest and greatest it's making me sad.

[image]

Does anyone know how to turn this inspection or feature off?  I have tried for the last hour turning off every inspection I can see without success.

Comment: did you always get this error? maybe rebuild/reimport projects etc. can help as well

Comment: IntelliJ often can help you solve the problem. Did you put your cursor on the code which is marked incorrect and then press Alt+Enter? It might suggest a solution.

Comment: In which class does setValueBean resides? this.setValue doesnt work?

Comment: @user140547 Only since upgrading to the newest version of Intellij.

Comment: @JustinL Yes of course I tried both putting my cursor over it and waiting for the red light bulb with help options in addition to the alt+enter trick without any success.  I don't believe there is a fix that it could apply and so it has nothing to offer.

Comment: @aviad The setValue method resides on both the ComboBox.class and the TextField.class.  I can do this.setValue but it doesn't remove the red line error warning.